# Rails sanitize isn't allowing rgb color

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rgb, wysiwyg, sanitize

I have a wysiwyg that allows users to format a text area.  I'm using `sanitize` and I'm passing in arrays of allowed tags and allowed attributes:

`<%= sanitize @record.notes, tags: %w(strong em u div span br h1 h2 h3 h4 ul ol li table thead tbody th tr td img hr a), attributes: %w(style colspan rowspan text-align class href target src href) %>`

Everything works properly except for style attributes with color specified with rgb.

For example, this input shows the color properly:

`<span style="color: red;">PRODUCTS</span>`

But this input doesn't work, and the style attribute is stripped blank:

`<span style="color: rgb(226, 80, 65);">PRODUCTS</span>`

Is there any way to get the rgb color working properly?

EDIT: For reference, I'm on Rails 4.2.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently [Loofah](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah) handles the sanitize function under the hood, and it defaults to removing some functions.  RGB color seems to be treated as a function.

There's currently a [pull request](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah/pull/123) to allow whitelisting of particular functions that should address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you need to do is to find the right combination of rgb becasue when I tried this

```
<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">PRODUCTS 1</span>
```

it gives me red here

```
<span style="color: red;">PRODUCTS</span>
```

maybe you need to use a colour picker to know what combination of rgb to use when you need to match a colour

Comment: rgb(255, 0, 0) doesn't work for me either.  I'm on Rails 4.2.10 by the way, I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: this is an html code, don't expect rails/ruby  version to be the issue. I suspect you might have another CSS rule affecting the element. Can you use inspect element in the chrome developer tool? that will tell you more

Comment: It's the rails sanitize method that's stripping out the style though.  When the color is "red", the resulting html is `<span style="color: red;">PRODUCTS</span>`.  When the color is rgb, the resulting html is `<span style>PRODUCTS</span>`